# To prove that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the smallest subfield of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: proof-verification, complex-numbers, field-theory, integers, rational-numbers

Assumption: There exsits $F$ which is a subfield of $\mathbb{C}$ such that $F\subsetneq \mathbb{Q}$.

Claim: $\mathbb{Z}\subset F$.

Proof: Let $m \in \mathbb{Z^+ }$. We know, that $1 \in F$. Taking $\displaystyle\underbrace{1+1+1+...+1}_{m \text{ times}}=m.1=m\in F$.Again, $F$ being a field, for any $m \in F  \implies -m \in F$. And $0\in F$ is trivial.

Hence, $ m\in \mathbb{Z} \implies m \in F \implies $ $\mathbb{Z}\subset F$.

Now, by assumption, $\exists \ w\in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $w\ \notin F $. Now, $w=p/q=pq^{-1}$ for some $p, q \in \mathbb{Z}$, with $q \neq 0$.

As per our proven claim, $p, q \in F$. Again, $F$ being a field, $w=pq^{-1}\in  F$.  A contradiction.

Hence, $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq F $, for any subfield $F$ of $\mathbb{C}$.

Is this correct? Kindly verify.

Comment: The idea is correct, though when you checked that $\mathbb{Z}\subseteq F$ you assumed that $m$ is positive. If you want a very formal proof then you have to write that since all elements of $F$ must have an additive inverse we conclude that the negative integers are in $F$ as well.

Comment: I shouldn't have missed that point. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @Mark, Is it correct now?

Comment: Yes, it is fine.

Comment: Duplicate of [A field with characteristic $0$ contains $\mathbb Q$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868484/a-field-with-characteristic-0-contains-mathbb-q)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the mapping ${\Bbb Z}\rightarrow{\Bbb C}:m\mapsto m\cdot 1$, where $1$ is the unit element in ${\Bbb C}$, is a ring monomorphism and so the image $\{m\cdot 1\mid m\in{\Bbb Z}\}$ can be identified with $\Bbb Z$. This probably better reflects your first part.

Secondly, you can prove straightforwardly that that $\Bbb C$ contains a copy of $\Bbb Q$ by starting with the copy of $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: I want the proof to be very basic here. I don't have much depth in field theory. This answer will be of help when I proceed further :)