# How to prove a number system is a fraction field of another?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, commutative-algebra, fraction-field

For example, how can I show that $\mathbb{Q}$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}$? Or that $\mathbb{C}$ is the fraction field of $\mathbb{R}$?

I understand that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a subring of $\mathbb{Q}$ & each r in $\mathbb{Q}$ can be written as a fraction r = a/b with a,b in $\mathbb{Z}$ and no proper subfield of $\mathbb{Q}$ has that property. But is there some general way to show this for the other number systems?

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is its own field of fractions, since it is already a field.

Comment: Not sure how that answers my question. Also, aren't $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ also fields?

Comment: Whats your definition of $\mathbb{Q}$? Usually $\mathbb{Q}$ is definded to be the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of rational numbers here.

Comment: Sure, but whats your definition of "rational number", the usual one is "an element in the fraction field of $\mathbb{Z}$". So there is nothing to prove.

Comment: Ah I'm running in circles. So the fraction field of $\mathbb{R}$ is not $\mathbb{C}$ but instead $\mathbb{R}$ itself? Why?

Comment: @BigD4J: A fraction field for an integral domain $R$ is the smallest field containing $R$ as a subring, or put differently, it is the smallest extension of the ring $R$ to a ring $F(R)$ that has all the multiplicative inverses $x^{-1}$ for every $x\in R\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: And in $\mathbb R$, every element $x\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$ already have their inverses in $\mathbb R$. Thus $\mathbb R$ is already its own fraction field. The simple way to say this is to say, that $\mathbb R$ is already a field (meaning that all non-zero elements have inverses).

Comment: Regarding $\mathbb C$, it is the *algebraic closure* of $\mathbb R$, which is something quite different. Both $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R$ are fields, the former being an extension field of the latter.

Comment: Maybe I'm confusing field extensions with fraction fields. I know $\mathbb{C}$ is a field extension of $\mathbb{R}$. I thought this translated to $\mathbb{C}$ being the field of fractions of $\mathbb{R}$, but I must have that mixed up.

Comment: OK, that makes sense then :)

Comment: Isn't it trivial that $\mathbb{C}$ is its own field of fractions? Is the case for $\mathbb{R}$ non-trivial?

Comment: @BigD4J by the definition above it is trivial to show that every field is its own field of fractions.

Comment: @Matt Samuel that's what I'm confused about as well. If  $\mathbb{Z}$ is its own field of fractions, how can  $\mathbb{Q}$ also be the field of fractions of  $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @BigD4J $\mathbb Z$ is not a field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *universal mapping property* of localizations (e.g. fraction fields) yields an easy **test** for (unique) isomorphism, cf. $3.2$ below, from Atiyah & MacDonald, *Commutative Algebra*, p. $39$.

In OP: $\:\!A\,$ is a domain and $\,S\,$ is the set of nonzero elements in $A,\,$ so $\,S\,$ contains no zero-divisors, so condition $(ii)$ in $3.2$ simplifies to $\,g:A\to B\,$ is an injection, so $3.2$ specializes to

**Corollary** $\,B\,$ is isomorphic to the quotient field of $A\,$ if $\,B\,$ contains an isomorphic image $\bar A$ of $A$ such that every $\,0\neq a\in A\,$ maps to a unit $\, \bar a = g(a)\,$ in $B,\,$ and every $\,q\in B\,$ is a fraction over $\bar A,\,$ i.e. $\,q  = \bar a_1 \bar a_2^{-1}\,$ for some $\,a_i\in A,\, a_2\neq 0$.

**Remark** $ $ More generally an analogous corollary holds for the [total ring of fractions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_ring_of_fractions) of a commutative ring - which inverts every $\,s\in S = $ all regular elements (non-zero-divisors).

[image]
[image]

Comment: The universal property of the fraction field $Q$ of $A$ is: every embedding of $A$ into a field $K$ uniquely extends to an embedding of $Q$ into $K$ (i.e. $Q$ is the most general (universal) field-image of $A).$ As above, can deduce this from the more general universal property of localizatations ("partial" rings of fractions)