# Prove the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$ is the ring $F((x))$ of formal Laurent series.

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

Prove the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$ is the ring $F((x))$ of formal Laurent series.

$F[[x]]$ is contained in $F((x))$.  So there's at least a ring homomorphism that is injective.  Can also see it's injective because the kernel of such a mapping would be trivial because $0$ is the same in either. Not sure if showing they are isomorphic is the best way to do this.

$\displaystyle \sum_{n \ge N} a_nx^n \in F((x))$

Im not sure how I would define the mapping. maybe theres a better way

Comment: Hint: use the [universal property of the fraction field.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1221595/242)

Comment: @BillDubuque That seems like a useful property but I'm not immediately seeing how I apply it here

Comment: Identifying $\,F[[x]]\,$ with its injective image in the field $\,F((x))\,$ then the Corollary implies that it suffices to prove that every element of $\,F((x))\,$ is a fraction over $\,F[[x]],\,$ which is clear:  every element has form $\,f(x)/x^n,\,$ for $\,f(x)\in F[[x]].\ \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field of fractions of an integral domain is the smallest field that the domain injects into. The homomorphism that sends a power series to itself is an injective homomorphism into $F((x))$, since every power series is also a Laurent series. If $F$ is the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$, then $f$ injects into $F((x))$, so we just need to check that the smallest subfield of $F((x))$ containing $F[[x]]$ is $F((x))$ itself. But this is clear: since $x^n$ is a power series for all $n\geq 0$, then any subfield containing all power series contains $x^{-n}$ as well. Thus, such a subfield contains all sums of power series and finitely many negative powers of $x$, which is exactly the field of Laurent series $F((x))$. Thus, $F((x))$ is indeed the field of fractions of $F[[x]]$.

Comment: Why should that subfield contain finitely many negative powers of $x$? Why not infinitely many?