# Isomorphism Field of Fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, group-isomorphism

Trying to figure out if you have integral domains A and B that are isomorphic then their respective field of fractions,F and K, are also isomorphic by $\theta(ab^{-1})=\theta(a)\theta(b)^{-1}$. How can you $\theta$ is an isomorphism?  For one-to-one I figure show ker$\theta$=0 and use pigeonhole to show onto but not sure.  And for addition  would showing $\theta(ab^{-1} + cd^{-1}) = \theta(ad+bc)(bd)^{-1})$ be on the right track.  Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the *universal* property of fraction fields: $ $ if $\,D\,$ is a domain with fraction field $\,F\,$ then any ring injection $\,h:D\to K\,$  into a field $\,K\,$ extends uniquely to  $\,\hat h : F\to K,\,$ via $\,\hat h (a/b) = h(a)h(b)^{-1}.$

Comment: See also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/665409/242) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1221595/242) for further details.