# What does $\subseteq$ mean regarding integral domains and their localizations?

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I came across the following in my commutative algebra notes

> If $R$ is a domain with quotient field $K$ and $S$ is a multiplicative set, then we have the inclusions $R \subseteq R_S \subseteq K.$

The set $R_S = \left\{\frac{r}{s} \, | \, r \in R, \, s \in S\right\}$ is the localization of $R$ at $S$.

What do the $\subseteq$'s mean in this context? To me, it can't mean set inclusion in the traditional sense because $R_S$ is a collection of equivalence classes $\frac{r}{s}$. Does $\subseteq$ mean that there is a monomorphism between the rings?

Thanks!

**Edit** To basically ask the same question with different terminology, does $R \subseteq R_S$, for example, mean that we can **embed** R into $R_S$?

Comment: as far as I know the symbol $\subseteq$ just have a meaning in mathematics

Comment: @Masacroso I thought that too. But if that's true, how can an element $r \in R$ also be in $R_S$ if $R_S$ is the set of equivalence classes?

Comment: Every fraction $r/s$ is an element of $K$ isn't it? And yes, $R$ is a subset of $S^{-1}R$ (in this definition): every element $r\in R$ is expressible as $r/1\in S^{-1}R$. When you generalize this definition to contexts where zero divisors may appear, that's when you need equivalence classes.

Comment: @runway44 That makes sense! If you make this comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it =)

Comment: @runway44 Not unless you perform set-theoretic surgery to splice the domain into the quotient field.  It all depends on how the quotient field is constructed *set theoretically* (which we usually ignore in algebra since one key point of algebra is to [abstract away from any internal structure of elements).](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/118922/242) Here what is important is the [universal property of the localization](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/655291/242) - which yields the sought unique embedding.